# Subir otra aplicación con mismo nombre en Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Acabo de eliminar una aplicación de [Google console](https://play.google.com/console/) y de la App Store.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo subir una aplicación nueva y no se si pueda subirla con el mismo nombre de la app que elimine.

Me refiero al nombre de la app. ¿Es posible volver a usar el nombre de la app eliminada?

me metí a la consola de Google y de apple developer, le di a la opción de "No publicar" y tienen el estado de "Eliminadas por ti". Acabo de verificar que ya no salen ni en google play ni applestore.

Entonces puedo subir una aplicación realizada en otro lenguaje con el mismo nombre de la anterior app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes subir otra aplicación con el mismo nombre que alguna que se encuentre en tu consola, pero no debes usar algún `package name` que se encuentre registrado en tu consola,

Es decir puedes subir otra aplicación con el mismo nombre pero esta debe tener diferente `applicationId` o `package name`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El lenguaje con la que sea creada es indistinto.